# How to decide on a partitioning scheme?

Tags: linux, partition, slackware

I am changing my current partition scheme (personal development laptop, dual boot) to remove the Windows partition and leave only my Slackware64 instance. What thought should go into my partitioning? I have been keeping `/` and `/home` in separate partitions, as well as a `swap` partition too. How do I decide what other partitions would be good to have in their own section of the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me /home partition is automatic for back-ups and ease of upgrading/installing new systems.  You can even (usually) share your /home between differing OSes (doesn't apply now, but you never know).  I keep it tidy (< USB drive size) so I can move it around easily.

Other than that, I haven't noticed much benefit to partitioning other things for home PC use.  Doesn't necessarily apply here, but on my main machine I will usually have a small /boot partition for my bootloader and then will part off my "priority" back-ups. E.g., maybe a partition for photographs that I can clonezilla easily (this is in addition to rsync'ing to an external HD and a remote location - ok, my parents' basement).  I do this mainly because I don't want my wife to ax murder me should I ever accidentally rm /photos (yes, I did it once - that was when I stopped creating any sub-directories with the same names as root directories).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly for a personal laptop any more partitions are just additional overhead in my opinion, that results in more work but no gain. I can see why /home as a separate partition makes sense, but on a personal machine even that isn't really necessary I think. However opinion on this varies greatly, so I'm sure some other views will be presented, there probably is not one single answer to this.

Comment: As [mentioned](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12319/12334#12334), one advantage of keeping `/home` partition separate is to ease system re-installation.