# How should I distribute files/packages/software across multiple drives?

Tags: files, mount, hard-disk, directory-structure, shared-partition

I am primarily a Windows user, but I am starting to use Linux more as I realize all the features it has. In Windows, I install my software that I use regularly on my 120GB SSD, along with the OS, while all other stuff goes in a large HDD. In Linux however, all personal user data is stored in /home, and while I could always just mount /home with the HDD, then I would have trouble if I wanted to install something onto my SSD, and vice-versa.

Comment: In Linux you can mix and match at great length how you map various paths to various devices. And sw packages can often be installed in configurable locations. Ability to install something somewhere is not something to worry about, but you may think about performance, reliability, etc. You might find interesting this Q&A, for example:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89213/partitioning-using-2-hard-disks-ssd-and-non-ssd-in-linux. Or google for `linux ssd hdd partition scheme`.

Comment: After reading that link I think I understand now. I didn't really consider mounting sub-directories of the base /xxx directories. Thanks!